# How to brush up on PHP?

Tags: php

I have an interview on Tuesday for a PHP job. I've been programming in PHP for about 6 years, but mostly ad-hoc self-built systems, it wasn't until about a year ago that I started to adopt frameworks and get more OOPy. These are familiar concepts from other languages though. What can I do to brush up and ace my interview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Read some php q's on SO?
- Build something? A twitter tool, using the API?
- Get at least an overview on CakePHP/Symfony/Zend (a lot of people seem to be asking about these)

Comment: I find that the best way for me to ever refresh my PHP skills is to answer questions on SO. Because if I'm not doing it right, people tell me. A LOT of people tell me.

Comment: Chacha102, correct. SO is great for peer-review.

Comment: I've used Cake for a project or two. Perhaps I'll snoop through the "PHP" tag on SO. For some reason, that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by reading the following question: ["What PHP-Specific Questions would You Ask in an Interview?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305654/what-php-specific-questions-would-you-ask-in-a-job-interview)

Answer (score 2):

Ya Googling for interview questions would be good as well as general searching.. In all honesty though I believe you loose more jobs over being to nervous then lack of knowledge.. My advice is go out for a beer with friends tonight, do some fun stuff for the next few days and just RELAX.

Just my 2 cents

Mike

Comment: I want to agree with you except for the fact he's nervous because he's not familiar with all the misc stuff out there and the best way for him to get less nervous is to boost his self confidence about his skills.  So actually some misc studying is going to be the best thing to make him less nervous.  If he was to brush off the issue, he'll walk into interview feeling both nervous AND guilty for not studying while he was out drinking.

Comment: Hi Travis.. You do bring up a valid point. So... why not make it a hybrid of the two as a good solution. Yes do some studying but also realize that you have experience.. And at the same time try to relax over the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

Crack open your old code, and find as much as you can thats wrong with it. Considering how much room PHP gives you to mess things up, you should have no problems pointing out what you could have done better.

Answer (score 1):

Zend administers PHP 5 training and certification, and they do offer practice exams online.  They seem to charge $22 for ten practice exams.

Pardon this spam about a non-free suggestion, but it could be a lot quicker and give a more comprehensive set of questions than ad hoc googling for interview questions.

http://shop.zend.com/en/php-certification/zend-php-certification-online-practice-testing.html